# Error: You made a reference to a non-existent script @php artisan package:discover

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am getting error at running **composer dump-autoload** at laravel project

```
composer dump-autoload
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
You made a reference to a non-existent script @php artisan package:discover
```

Then executing php artisan package:discover returns

```
Discovered Package: barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
Discovered Package: cartalyst/sentinel
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: laracasts/generators
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

Then again getting the same error

```
composer dump-autoload
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
You made a reference to a non-existent script @php artisan package:discover
```

What may be wrong? `composer self-update` or `composer global update` not helping.

Comment: update composer `composer global update` or `composer self-update`

Comment: have you tried uninstalling composer, then installing the latest version??

Comment: I think `composer self-update` already do that

Comment: one last thing, did you close the terminal after composer update and start again??

Comment: Trying for few days now

Comment: try deleting `@` symbol from composer.json file

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, I think that `composer dump-autoload` is working even with that warning. (thanks to the user:[Sohel0415](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2175689/) comments) composer was not able to run 
 script with @ symbol in composer.json file.

If you want to get rid of this warning simply do

`composer dump-autoload --no-scripts`

or

you may delete the script with @ `"post-autoload-dump": []` from you `"scripts": {}` in the `composer.json` file temporarily, and it should be all good.

Answer (score 4):

You may also try to update your global `composer` package with this command.

```
composer self-update
```

I was having this error because I had an old version of composer that wasn't reading the @ symbols.

Comment: This solution worked for me. The Docker container was running an older version of composer, so had to rebuild it to install the current latest version.

Answer (score 1):

For myself, I found that in composer.json I had the wrong references to the php command: I changed the lines that specified a location for php, for example:

```
"@/usr/local/bin/php artisan key:generate"
```

to:

```
"@php artisan key:generate"
```

After those changes, I was able to execute the command "composer update" with no error.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed

```
 "scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@/usr/local/bin/php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@/usr/local/bin/php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@/usr/local/bin/php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

to

```
"scripts": {
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@/usr/local/bin/php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
    ]
}
```

in composer.json

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue trying to add composer native `cache-clear` command to a custom script I made called `composer nuke`. I was using it as `@clear-cache` and got the message, "You made a reference to a non-existent script @clear-cache".

I guess the `@` symbol is only for custom commands. I had to put `composer cache-clear` inside the custom command and the error was resolved and the command ran as expected then.