# laravel SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'name.system_functions' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have just cloned a Laravel project. I tried to run composer install and php artisan migrate but both return this error

> > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>
> > @php artisan package:discover
>
> In Connection.php line 664:
>
> > SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'name.system_functions' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `system_functions` where `name` = test limit 1)
>
> In Connection.php line 326:
>
> > SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'name.system_f
> >       unctions' doesn't exist

I use MySQL and Sequel Pro has already created database for this project.

```
Schema::create('system_functions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name',64);
        $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
        $table->boolean('is_active');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Data in this table is created by database seeding. I have tried php artisan db:seed will return this error too.

Comment: Check your database setting and share the project link that you have cloned.

Comment: `php artisan config:clear` then run again

Answer (score 1):

Try run `composer dump-autoload` before running `composer install` and `php artisan migrate`

Comment: running composer dump-autoload will return this error too

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

try `composer global update` or `composer self-update`

**Solution 2**

`composer dump-autoload` works fine but after running dump-autoload it tries to run scripts written in `scripts.post-autoload-dump` array in composer.json file, but composer is not able to run script with @ symbol in composer.json file. In order to get rid over this warning run

```
composer dump-autoload --no-scripts
```

And if you want to get rid of it permanently then remove script with @ post-autoload-dump": [] from your composer.json file.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760744/error-you-made-a-reference-to-a-non-existent-script-php-artisan-packagediscov)